# Look-up equal element in TreeSet

Tags: java, treeset

I'm developing a historic view of some elements. Each element has a start and end date. The periods may not overlap, so each start date has to be equal or later then its predecessor's end date. If an end date is null the element is active from its start date until the end date is known.

For testing purposes I have created this class:

```
public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>
{
    Integer start;
    Integer end;

    public Entry(Integer s, Integer e)
    {
        start = s;
        end = e;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj instanceof Entry)
        {
            return compareTo((Entry) obj) == 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry o)
    {
        if (o.end != null // other ends before or when this starts
                && (o.end.equals(start) || o.end < start ))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (end != null // other starts after or when this ends
                && (o.start.equals(end) || o.start > end ))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I use a TreeSet to sort the elements. Now I have the problem that I cannot get the current active or first coming element.

Looking at the JavaDoc the ceiling method should do the trick:

> Returns the least element in this set greater than or equal to the given element, or null if there is no such element.

However this doesn't work.

In a test case I create a TreeSet with a bunch of Entries:

```
TreeSet<Entry> ts = new TreeSet<Entry>();
ts.add(new Entry(1, 3));
ts.add(new Entry(3, 5));
ts.add(new Entry(5, 7));
ts.add(new Entry(7, 9));
ts.add(new Entry(9, 11));
ts.add(new Entry(11, 13));
ts.add(new Entry(13, 15));
```

Then I get the ceiling using the following code:

```
ts.ceiling(new Entry(5, null));
```

The result I expect is the Entry with start 5 and end 7 (the 'equal' Entry). However the result is the Entry with start 7 and end 9 (the greater Entry).
Both results qualify as equal to or greater than the given element. But since the JavaDoc mentions it returns the least element, I expect the 5-7 Entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining what is to be the least element (by defining the `compareTo`).

And you ARE yourself stating that:

> "Both results qualify as equal"

So when the API refers to the least element, it refers to the element after or equal (ceil) to the argument *in the ordered set*.
Now print your ordered set:

[(1, 3), (3, 5), (5, 7), (7, 9), (9, 11), (11, 13), (13, 15)]

So ceiling first looks for the element equal to `5, null` (meaning `compareTo` returns 0) and if it finds one returns that one. You have two elements that are equal (so no need to look for the one after that).

*That* is what the ceiling method documentation is refering to, the the order in the set (not by setting up some sort of new comparison).

> public E ceiling(E e)
>
> Returns the least element *in this set* greater than or equal to the given element

See [TreeSet#ceiling(E e) API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#ceiling%28E%29)

So it finds either `5, 7` or `7,9` (which are both equal to `5, null`) and returns the one it finds first, which is `7,9` according to the implementation.

A TreeSet is actually a Tree-structure behind the scenes (doh) and which node in that tree it hits of two equal ones depend on the details of the implementation and possibly order of insertion.

Your compareTo/equals doesn't obey the normal/recommended rules (certainly bad for a Tree trying to use them). If A and B are equal and C and B are equal then A and C should be equal, that is *not* the case with your compareTo function.

Comment: Then how come if I do the same with a set of Strings in stead of Entries `TreeSet<String> t = new TreeSet<String>(); t.add("a"); t.add("b"); t.add("c");` , `t.ceiling("b");` spits out `"b"`? You're stating it should give be "c".

Comment: Sorry a bit unclear/wrong about that perhaps but ceiling returns greater than or *equal*. A TreeSet is actually a Tree-structure behind the scenes (!), which node in that tree it hits of two equal ones depend on the implementation

Comment: So to be clear (updated answer a little bit too), if you had use a List instead it would find the first one in the list if you used `get()`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly a TreeSet is capable of having two 'equal' elements? If this is true, which type of collection should I use to prohibit the use of duplicate elements and ordered by compareTo()?

Comment: No! But your collection does *not* have two equal elements. `5, null` is not in the set and the other two that it is equal to are not equal to each other, which is a bad implementation). The add method doesn't allow adding another element that is already there. Try adding `5,null`it won't be added. But your compareTo function is not correctly implemented, not obeying the normal rules for equal/compareTo

Comment: Basically, because your `compareTo` function doesn't obey the proper restrictions, all the guarantees you're supposed to have are really weirdly/unpredictably affected.

Comment: I know that my equals() is hackish but I don't know what I am missing in my compareTo() or what exactly I am doing wrong. Can someone provide a solution for my case?

Comment: If A and B are equal and B and C are equal (compareTo => 0) then A and C should be equal, that is not the case with your compareTo function. In your case B is  `5, null` and the other two A and C. You need to fix that.

Comment: After some puzzling I came to the conclusion that I cannot correctly use the compareTo() in this case because there are 4 cases: before, after, equals and overlaps. The latter is the source of the problem. This left me with two options; implement my own NavigatableSet or add another hack on top of this. As I don't have the time to do the first I have chosen the second. The 'solution' I have chosen is to do the lookup with two equal dates ( `5, 5` in the test case), this does exactly what I want. Thanks for the explanation guys ;-)

Comment: Sounds like a fair conclusion.